# Java code for arranging blocks in rectangular area

Tags: java

I want to arrange blocks of equal sizes into a rectangular area like follows

[image]

So the input should be number of blocks and the output should be (n1, n2, n3...) where n1 is the number of blocks in row 1 and so on....

For example for the above image out will be (2,3,2) for input 7.

Is there some library to achieve this ?  The constraint i want is to arrange in lowest number of rows with each row of same width. also I want is no rows should contain more than 4 image.

Comment: I'd be staggered if there is a library out there that supports this specific, unusual scenario. Are the same-sized blocks always guaranteed to sum to the same width? Does it matter which order the rows are in?

Comment: @Duncan I mean not exactly similar but close one .... Row order doesn't matter....Well the code must aarrange them so all the rows must have the same width.

Comment: I've voted to close as "too broad". The requirements are vague and any solution would need to be many lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, this is going to be a custom job. For example if I was just given the 7 blocks that you mention I could end up with (2,3,2) like you did or (2,2,3) or (3,2,2) or (4,2,1), etc.

To put together a mathematically well formed solution you are going to have to constrain it more. e.g. no more than x rows, rows are added in the following order, new rows can / cannot be inserted between existing rows etc.

writing that kind of algorithm from scratch is doable, but you need to constrain the possibilities more to have it work as you described.

Comment: Well the most clear constraint i can think of is arrange in lowest number of rows with each row of same width

Comment: Then you may want to edit your question because your example with this constraint would only have 2 rows. one with 4 images and one with 3 images. can you elaborate on what you want from the library? is it a row index with the position (x,y) and the length/width for each image on the row? if all you want is the number of rows and images in each row you can get it by this: numrows = numimages/4 and numlastrowimages = numimages % 4. where all rows but the last have 4 images.